# If $(x_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy, show subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$ such that $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}|x_{n_{k}} - x_{n_{k+1}}| < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

If $(x_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy, show that it has a subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$ such that $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}|x_{n_{k}} - x_{n_{k+1}}| < \infty$

**Attempt:**

Since $x_n$ is Cauchy and since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete $\Rightarrow$ then $(x_n)$ converges to a point $x$ in the set $\mathbb{R}$. This means that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall \ m,n > N_{1} \ |x_{m} - x_{n}| < \epsilon$.

Since $(x_n)$ converges $\Rightarrow$ $(x_n)$ is bounded. So by the Bolzano Weirstrauss theorem, there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$ that converges to $x$. That is:  $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N_{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall \ n_{k} > N_{2} \ |x_{n_{k}} - x| < \epsilon$.

Therefore:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} |x_{n_{k}} - x_{n_{k+1}}| = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} |x_{n_{k}} - x_{m} + x_{m} - x + x - x_{n_{k+1}}| \leq \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}(|x_{n_{k}} - x_{m}| + |x_{m} - x| + |x - x_{n_{k+1}}|) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}|x_{n_{k}} - x_{m}| + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}|x_{m} - x| + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}|x - x_{n_{k+1}}| < \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon $$

**Final Thought:** Two things:

1) Am I interpreting that $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}|x_{n_{k}} - x_{n_{k+1}}| < \infty$ means the series is convergent?

2) I don't know if I needed to include the $x_{m}$ cauchy term or if this is the right approach all together. My reasoning for it was that since the other sequences are convergent then their series would also be convergent so I applied that. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty |x_m - x| < \epsilon / 3$? For that matter, how do you any of those infinite sums are less than $\epsilon / 3$?

Comment: Since they are all convergent sequences this means the series would converge and as such, I could make my $\epsilon$ as small as I want.....well that was my reasoning....it may be flawed.

Comment: You can make each term $|x_m - x|$ smaller than any $\epsilon > 0$. Sure. But you are adding those terms infinitely many times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is wrong. If you know that all terms are smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ it doesn't mean their infinite sum is smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ as well.

Here is a possible solution: since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy we can conclude that there is $n_1$ such that for all $m,p\geq n_1$ we have $|x_m-x_p|<\frac{1}{2}$. Next, there is $n_2>n_1$ such that for all $m,p\geq n_2$ we have $|x_m-x_p|<\frac{1}{2^2}$. Continue by induction, every time choose $n_k>n_{k-1}$ such that for all $m,p\geq n_k$ we have $|x_m-x_p|<\frac{1}{2^k}$. And now $(x_{n_k})$ is the required subsequence. Since $n_{k+1}, n_k\geq n_k$ we know that $|x_{n_k}-x_{n_{k+1}}|<\frac{1}{2^k}$, this is true for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. And then:

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_{n_k}-x_{n_{k+1}}|\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}<\infty$

Answer (score 6):

Since the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, there is a $n_1\in\mathbb N$ such that$$m,n\geqslant n_1\implies\lvert x_m-x_n\rvert<\frac12.$$And there is a $n_2>n_1$ such that$$m,n\geqslant n_2\implies\lvert x_m-x_n\rvert<\frac1{2^2}.$$And there is a $n_3>n_2$ such that$$m,n\geqslant n_3\implies\lvert x_m-x_n\rvert<\frac1{2^3}.$$And so on. Therefore$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lvert x_{n_k}-x_{n_{k+1}}\rvert<\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^k}=1.$$

Comment: Is the reason we can pick $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ explicitly because we know the sequence is Cauchy? And from this idea we construct an infinite series that we know for sure converges and compare it to that.

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt doesn't work at all.  You're adding infinitely many terms, but all you know so far is that each is less than $\epsilon$.  How are you getting the sum to be less than $\epsilon$?

Hint: Take $N_k$ so that for all $m, n \le N_k$, $|x_m - x_n| < 1/2^k$. Then in particular $|x_{N_k} - x_{N_{k+1}}| < 1/2^k$.

Comment: Did you mean $m,n \geq N_k$ ?

Comment: Nice answer, concise and to the point.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your proof: for example, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty |x_m - x|$ doesn't converge unless $x_m = x$ already (and it can be impossible if sequence doesn't reach limit). You also don't need to take convergent subsequence - original sequence was Cauchy, thus already convergent.

The main idea is correct - we need to use Cauchy criteria. Take some $M_0$ s.t. if $m \geqslant M_0$ and $n \geqslant M_0$ then $|x_m - x_n| < 1$, some $M_1 > M_0$ s.t. if $m \geqslant M_1$ and $n \geqslant M_1$ then $|x_m - x_n| < \frac{1}{2}$, ... - for any $i$ take $M_i > M_{i - 1}$ s.t. if $m \geqslant M_i$ and $n \geqslant M_i$ then $|x_m - x_n| < \frac{1}{2^i}$. Now take $x_{M_0}, x_{M_1}, \ldots$ as subsequence:
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_{M_k} - x_{M_{k + 1}}| \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}$ that converges.